# I am trying to solve this question about optimal stopping theory. I don't know how to get started. Any hints would be very helpful

Tags: martingale, stopping-time

Let $Z = (Zn)_{n=0,1,...,N}$ be the Snell envelope of $X = (Xn)_{n=0,1,...,N}$ and $τ ∈ T_{0,N}$. Let $Z_n = M_n − A_n$ be the Doob decomposition of Z, then $Z_n^τ = M_n^τ − A_n^τ$ is the Doob decomposition of $Z_n^τ$ (do not prove this).

(a) Explain why $Aτ$ = $A_N^τ$ .

(b) Hence, prove that $Z_τ$ is a martingale if and only if $A_τ$ = 0.

Comment: Since $\tau \le N$, it is obvious that $A_N^{\tau} = A_{N\wedge \tau} = A_{\tau}$. Given that $Z_{\tau}$ is a single random variable, it does not make sense to say it is a martingale. Do you mean $Z^{\tau} =\{Z_n^{\tau}\}_{n=1}^N$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Snell envelope is the smallest super-martingale that is greater than $X$. Since $\tau \le N$, it is obvious that $A_N^{\tau} = A_{N\wedge \tau} = A_{\tau}$.

For part (b), note that, from the Doob decomposition, $M$ is a martingale, $A$ is increasing, $M_0=Z_0$, and $A_0=0$. If $Z^{\tau}= \{Z_n^{\tau}\}_{n=1}^N$ is also a martingale, then 
\begin{align*}
E(A_{\tau}) &= E(A_N^{\tau}) \\
&= E(M_N^{\tau} - Z_N^{\tau}) \\
&= M_0 - Z_0=0.
\end{align*}
Consequently, $A_{\tau}=0$, as $A_{\tau}$ is non-negative.